# I am trying to do a join table and I am getting ambiguous column error

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I want to join two tables, contacts and groups. I want to get the firstName column from contacts where the groups' column in contacts matches groups column in groups. When I enter my statement any column from contacts says it's ambiguous.

```
cursor.execute('SELECT groups.groups FROM contacts, groups LEFT JOIN contacts ON contacts.groups = groups.groups')
```

Comment: Tip - commas should never appear in a `from` clause.

Answer (score 1):

You are including the contacts table twice
I think you shuould do

```
select contacts.firstname
from contacts
left join groups 
on contacts.groups=groups.groups
```